# Can answers be posted on a closed question?

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

Prompted by [this](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/posts/26327/timeline).

As you can observe, an answer has been posted almost 2 hours after the question had been closed.

Is it a bug? Or is is expected that extremely high rep users can ignore the closed state? Or is it something else?

My current guess is that the answer was being typed while the question got locked and, without reloading the page, it got posted 2 hours later.

Comment: Actually "may" means "does one have the right". This meta question looks good  to me.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[Broken As Designed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/91922/how-was-this-answer-posted-after-this-question-was-closed): If you already started writing an answer it is possible to post it to a closed question for a while (~ 4 hours) if the client-side code that prevents you from doing so fails to run for some reason.

The usual reason for such a thing would be a Javascript blocker.

Comment: Are you saying that being able to post the answer (if the question becomes closed between when I start the answer & when I click to post it) is dependent on a Javascript blocker on my computer, or that anybody is able to post their answer, if they began it under that circumstance?